# How do I say: Something is 1/1.5 times as big as something else? e.g. using the analogy X is 1/3 (one-third) as big as Y

Tags: grammaticality

Here is my challenge:

According to the proper grammar of English:

My house is **TWICE (2X)** as big as yours.....Your house is **HALF (1/2)** as big as mine. CORRECT.

How do I then say that:

My house is **ONE AND A HALF (1.5X)** times as big as yours.....Your house is **1/1.5**?

Comment: Two-thirds [the size of], last time I did my sums. But maths terms don't often have idiomatic everyday equivalents. 'Scale factor 0.666...' (linear SF?)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth is quite right. With your formatting, your example would read, "Your house is **TWO-THIRDS (2/3)** as big as mine."

Comment: Idiomatically, *"My house is ONE AND A HALF (1.5X) times as big as yours."* would be "My house is 50% bigger than yours." or "My house is half as big again as yours."

Comment: @greybead I would say that as "my house is half again as big as yours".... splitting the *again* away from the *half* seems wrong to me.

Comment: See also [m-w's entry on *half again*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/half%20again%20as%20much/many%20as)

Comment: Thanks to all. 2/3 is perfect. We are so used to saying 1/X, hence the confusion. Never heard of "half again"...

Comment: @Hellion - have a look at Google Ngrams in British English and American English for "half as big again, half again as big" You will see that "half as big again" is far more popular in British English, and "half again as big" is only marginally more popular in American English. ("Half again as big" sounds weird to me :))

Comment: Just thought I'd mention a related idiom which is "time-and-half" when referring specifically to an overtime rate of 1.5. I think "half again" is legitimate, but I think it would tend to be used in specific constructions, like "you've seen the size of my house? Well his is half again bigger" or "bigger by half again" - I don't think it would be considered idiomatic, or clear, to follow the example in the question and say "my house is half again as big as yours". Nowadays, people would more readily resort to saying "50% bigger" or "bigger by another half".

Comment: Any question that begins with "According to the proper grammar of English" or words to that effect needs to be warned about believing everything people say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My house is (2x) *twice* as big as yours.
>
> My house is (⅓) *a third* as big as yours.
> My house is (½) *half* as big as yours.
>
> My house is (1⅓x) **a third** ***again*** as big as yours.
> My house is (1½x) **half** ***again*** as big as yours.

The use of *again* after a fractional expression is used to represent that something is of equal size *plus* the fractional number.

This is the sense of [*again*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/again) that's being used:

> [Merriam-Webster]
> **4** : in addition : BESIDES
> // *Again*, there is another matter to consider.

The use of *again* can come after any fractional representation.

---

Outside of the particular phrasing in this context, you might hear something like this:

> Give me a pint, and then half a pint *again*.

To paraphrase and analyze the context of its use in house sizes, it means the following:

> My house is [the same size] as yours and [this fraction] bigger [in addition].

---

The use of *half again* specifically is common enough that it's actually become an idiom:

> [**half again as much/many as**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/half%20again%20as%20much/many%20as)
> Merriam-Webster
> *US*
> —used to say that the size or amount of one thing is 50 percent more than another
> // If 100 people were expected and 150 came, *half again as many* people came as were expected.
> // This dress costs *half again as much* as that one.

Note that the definition includes *US*, so this could be less common in the UK.